# How to configure network on centos

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I was trying to setup go auto dial which uses cent OS, I am totally new to cent OS and don't know how to configure network on it, and without network I can't access the go auto CE portal.

*I tried putting my WiFi IP sub-net mask and default gateway, but when I try to access the given IP it shows me:*

[image]

Comment: are you tried to check your config via command `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all your network interfaces (to check your interface name, eth0 in following example, replace eth0 par your interface name read from the result of the following command):

```
[root@localhost]# ifconfig -a
```

if you use eth0 interface you should configure like following:

```
[root@localhost]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

---

```
## Configure eth0
#
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE="eth0" # interface name
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes # launch network in Linux boot
HWADDR=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF # your mac address
TYPE=Ethernet 
BOOTPROTO=static # static or dhcp
NAME="System eth0"
IPADDR=X.X.X.X # your ip address if static is chosen
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 # your netmask if static is chosen


[root@localhost]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
```

---

```
## Configure Default Gateway
#
# /etc/sysconfig/network

NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos6
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Restart Network Interface

```
[root@localhost]# /etc/init.d/network restart
```

Configure DNS Server

```
[root@localhost]# vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

---

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8      # Replace with your nameserver ip
nameserver 8.8.4.4      # Replace with your nameserver ip
```